# Stack data from columns to rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, stack

I am trying to stack financial values year wise in pandas Dataframe. But not able to get started.

All I have tried is

```
df1 = df.set_index(['refnum','y1gp','y2gp','y3gp']).stack()\
.reset_index(name='REV').rename(columns={'level_5':'Year'})
```

Existing:

| refnum | y1 | y1rev | y1gp | y2 | y2rev | y2gp | y3 | y3rev | y3gp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2021 | 300 | 200 | 2022 | 100 | 600 | 2023 | 300 | 300 |
| 10002 | 2020 | 300 | 200 | 2021 | 200 | 500 | 2022 | 300 | 300 |
| 10003 | 2021 | 300 | 200 | 2022 | 500 | 500 | 2023 | 300 | 300 |

Expected:

| refnum | year | REV | GP | Base Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2021 | 300 | 200 | BaseYear |
| 10001 | 2022 | 100 | 600 | BaseYear+1 |
| 10001 | 2023 | 300 | 300 | BaseYear+2 |
| 10002 | 2020 | 300 | 200 | BaseYear |
| 10002 | 2021 | 200 | 500 | BaseYear+1 |
| 10002 | 2022 | 300 | 300 | BaseYear+2 |
| 10003 | 2021 | 300 | 200 | BaseYear |
| 10003 | 2022 | 500 | 500 | BaseYear+1 |
| 10003 | 2023 | 300 | 300 | BaseYear+2 |

Comment: Where does the Base Year column come from?

Comment: Have to create one on the fly to keep track of calculations

Comment: But is it just the literal words "BaseYear", "BaseYear+1" etc? not some calculation?

Comment: int values 0,1,2,3 will work as well 0 being the base year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's convert the headers to a useable MultiIndex using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to go from wide-form to long. Then [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to create the BaseYear column.

```
# Save Columns
df = df.set_index('refnum')
# Create a MultiIndex with Numbers at the end and split into multiple levels
df.columns = (
    df.columns.str.replace(r'^(.*?)(\d+)(.*)$', r'\1\3/\2', regex=True)
        .str.split('/', expand=True)
)
# Wide Format to Long + Rename Columns
df = df.stack().droplevel(-1).reset_index().rename(
    columns={'y': 'Year', 'ygp': 'GP', 'yrev': 'REV'}
)
# Add Base Year Column
df['BaseYear'] = "BaseYear+" + df.groupby('refnum').cumcount().astype(str)
# df['BaseYear'] = df.groupby('refnum').cumcount()  # (int version)
```

`df`:

```
   refnum  Year   GP  REV    BaseYear
0   10001  2021  200  300  BaseYear+0
1   10001  2022  600  100  BaseYear+1
2   10001  2023  300  300  BaseYear+2
3   10002  2020  200  300  BaseYear+0
4   10002  2021  500  200  BaseYear+1
5   10002  2022  300  300  BaseYear+2
6   10003  2021  200  300  BaseYear+0
7   10003  2022  500  500  BaseYear+1
8   10003  2023  300  300  BaseYear+2
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
df.columns = [re.sub(r"y(\d+)(.*)", r"\2-\1", c) for c in df.columns]
x = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        df, stubnames=["", "gp", "rev"], sep="-", i="refnum", j="Base Year"
    )
    .rename(columns={"": "year"})
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by="refnum")
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   refnum  Base Year  year   gp  rev
0   10001          1  2021  200  300
3   10001          2  2022  600  100
6   10001          3  2023  300  300
1   10002          1  2020  200  300
4   10002          2  2021  500  200
7   10002          3  2022  300  300
2   10003          1  2021  200  300
5   10003          2  2022  500  500
8   10003          3  2023  300  300
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could use empty string as a stubname. Way cool! I was going to use `wide_to_long` but I wanted to avoid the `sort` step.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pivot_longer` from `pyjanitor`; for this scenario, you pass regexes to `names_pattern`, and the new column names in `names_to`:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
df.pivot_longer(index='refnum', 
                names_to=['year', 'REV', 'GP'], 
                names_pattern=['^y\d$', '.*rev$', '.*gp$']
               )

   refnum  year  REV   GP
0   10001  2021  300  200
1   10002  2020  300  200
2   10003  2021  300  200
3   10001  2022  100  600
4   10002  2021  200  500
5   10003  2022  500  500
6   10001  2023  300  300
7   10002  2022  300  300
8   10003  2023  300  300
```

If you want the base year included, you can modify the column labels that end with a number, before using `pivot_longer`:

```
(df.rename(columns = lambda col: f"{col}YEAR" 
                                 if col.endswith(('1','2','3')) 
                                 else col)
   .pivot_longer(index='refnum', 
                 names_to= ("Base Year", ".value"), 
                 names_pattern=r".(\d)(.+)", 
                 sort_by_appearance=True)
 )

   refnum Base Year  YEAR  rev   gp
0   10001         1  2021  300  200
1   10001         2  2022  100  600
2   10001         3  2023  300  300
3   10002         1  2020  300  200
4   10002         2  2021  200  500
5   10002         3  2022  300  300
6   10003         1  2021  300  200
7   10003         2  2022  500  500
8   10003         3  2023  300  300
```

labels associated with `.value` stay as column headers, while the rest are lumped into a new column (`base year`)